# TestDriven.NET hangs for tests that connect to the database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testdriven.net

So I'm writing a web service that connects to a remote PostgreSQL server, pulls some data and then I do stuff with the data.  Currently, I'm writing unit tests to ensure that I can grab the data and my `List<T>` has a count greater than zero.

I have a private PostgresSQL connection:

`private NpgsqlConnection _conn;`

In the test fixture setup, I open the connection:

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void TestFixtureSetUp()
{
    _conn = DAL.ConnectToPostgeSQL();
}
```

Write some tests...example:

```
[Test]
public void CanGetSubmissions()
{
    List<Submission> submission = DAL.GetSubmissions(_conn);
    Assert.GreaterThan(submission.Count, 0);
}
```

Then, I tear down to close out the connections:

```
[TestFixtureTearDown]
public void TestFixtureTearDown()
{
    _conn.Close();
    _conn.Dispose();
}
```

The trouble is that after the test(s) (can occur if I only run one test), it passes and then just hangs until I stop TestDriven.NET.

Any thoughts on this?  I'm thinking that it has to do with the PostgreSQL connection, because when I remove those, the tests will fail and everything tears down as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Open and close connection for each test - Setup & TearDown instead of TestFixtureSetup & TestFixtureTeardown

Comment: +1 It's always good practice to open a connection as late as possible and close it as early as possible.

Comment: Well, I thought this worked but, ran into the problem again after a few runs.

Comment: But still, open and close every time.

Comment: Yes. It's opening and closing everytime.  I just re-installed TestDriven.NET so we'll see if that helps anything.